# Symfony2 CRUD generates "The CRUD generator expects the entity object has a primary key field..."

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I got this error when generate CRUD:

```
The CRUD generator expects the entity object has a primary key field named "id" with a getId() method.
```

I can't find field that using id, I've check it several times.

This is the Doctrine:

```
Sifo\SchoolBundle\Entity\MstJabatan:
    type: entity
    table: mst_jabatan
    id:
        kode:
            type: string
            nullable: false
            length: 20
            fixed: false
            comment: ''
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        nama:
            type: string
            nullable: false
            length: 50
            fixed: false
            comment: ''
        otoritas:
            type: boolean
            nullable: false
            comment: ''
            default: '0'
        keterangan:
            type: string
            nullable: false
            length: 100
            fixed: false
            comment: ''
        aktif:
            type: boolean
            nullable: false
            comment: ''
            default: '1'
        timestamp:
            type: datetime
            nullable: false
            comment: ''
            default: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        operator:
            type: string
            nullable: false
            length: 20
            fixed: false
            comment: ''
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

This is the entity:

```
<?php

namespace Sifo\SchoolBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * MstJabatan
 */
class MstJabatan
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $kode;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $nama;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     */
    private $otoritas;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $keterangan;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     */
    private $aktif;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $timestamp;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $operator;


    /**
     * Get kode
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getKode()
    {
        return $this->kode;
    }

    /**
     * Set nama
     *
     * @param string $nama
     * @return MstJabatan
     */
    public function setNama($nama)
    {
        $this->nama = $nama;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nama
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNama()
    {
        return $this->nama;
    }

    /**
     * Set otoritas
     *
     * @param boolean $otoritas
     * @return MstJabatan
     */
    public function setOtoritas($otoritas)
    {
        $this->otoritas = $otoritas;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get otoritas
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getOtoritas()
    {
        return $this->otoritas;
    }

    /**
     * Set keterangan
     *
     * @param string $keterangan
     * @return MstJabatan
     */
    public function setKeterangan($keterangan)
    {
        $this->keterangan = $keterangan;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get keterangan
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getKeterangan()
    {
        return $this->keterangan;
    }

    /**
     * Set aktif
     *
     * @param boolean $aktif
     * @return MstJabatan
     */
    public function setAktif($aktif)
    {
        $this->aktif = $aktif;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get aktif
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getAktif()
    {
        return $this->aktif;
    }

    /**
     * Set timestamp
     *
     * @param \DateTime $timestamp
     * @return MstJabatan
     */
    public function setTimestamp($timestamp)
    {
        $this->timestamp = $timestamp;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get timestamp
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getTimestamp()
    {
        return $this->timestamp;
    }

    /**
     * Set operator
     *
     * @param string $operator
     * @return MstJabatan
     */
    public function setOperator($operator)
    {
        $this->operator = $operator;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get operator
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getOperator()
    {
        return $this->operator;
    }
}
```

Generated using this command:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:crud --entity=SifoSchoolBundle:MstJabatan --route-prefix=sifo_MstJabatan --with-write --format=yml
```

What caused this problem actually?

Comment: I have check all tables again but still cant find field name started with id especially for Primary and Foreign Key. Anyone have clue about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have overriden the default id behavior

```
id:
        kode:
            type: string
            nullable: false
            length: 20
            fixed: false
            comment: ''
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
```

so now your id field is called kode in the entity. and the CRUD generator is configured only to work with the ID field in entity and he simply can't find a property $id and method getId() in your autogenerated entity.

You can change the field name from kode to id and make an alias getter the getKode() method, or write your crud self by modifying generated CRUD files from other entity

Comment: Thank you, I think better change all PK to Id since this is new Project. Case Solved.